# Swift - Customizing cell content (UILabel, UIImageView)

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, uilabel, uicollectionviewcell

I would like to customize my `UICollectionViewCell` but it doesn't work how I would like it to work.

This is my code for the first cell:

```
class MainWishlistCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    let wishlistImage: UIImageView = {
        let v = UIImageView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.image = UIImage(named: "logoGroß")
        v.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0
        v.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        v.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 3, height: 3)
        v.layer.masksToBounds = false
        return v
    }()

    let wishlistLabel: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.text = "Main Wishlist"
        v.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir Next-Bold", size: 18)
        v.textColor = .darkGray
        v.textAlignment = .center
        return v
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }

    func commonInit() -> Void {
        contentView.addSubview(wishlistImage)
        contentView.addSubview(wishlistLabel)
        // constrain view to all 4 sides
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            wishlistImage.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor),
            wishlistImage.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor),
            wishlistImage.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor),
            wishlistImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant:150),

            wishlistLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: wishlistImage.bottomAnchor,constant: 1),
            wishlistLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor),
            wishlistLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor),
            wishlistLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor),
        ])
    }
}
```

And it looks like this:

[image]

**1. Problem** - Why is the label not `bold`?

**2. Problem** - Why is there no `cornerRadius`?

**3. Problem** - Why does `shadow` not appear (bottom + right) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first problem as @pigeon_39 said you should write your font name without white space.

For the second and third problems, you can use this solution:

```
func addShadow() {
    let cornerRadius: CGFloat = 5
    self.wishlistImage.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.wishlistImage.bounds, cornerRadius: cornerRadius).cgPath
    self.wishlistImage.layer.shadowRadius = cornerRadius
    self.wishlistImage.layer.shadowOffset = .zero
    self.wishlistImage.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3
    self.wishlistImage.layer.shadowRadius = 10
    self.wishlistImage.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
    self.wishlistImage.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
}
```

And call it after setting constraints.

Comment: what do you mean by after setting the constraints? Calling `addShadow()` after `func commonInit()` doesn't work for me.

Comment: I mean call it in `commonInit` after activating constraint

Comment: that worked for you?? There is a shadow around the label but nothing happened with the image :D

Comment: Are you sure that you are correct about `wishListImage` vs `wishListLabel`? I wrote that for `wishListImage` as you see!

Comment: yes. I set `roundRect:`to `self.wishlistImage.bounds` .  I just had `self`before.. Now it no longer appears at all

Comment: It's wrong setting round rect to self.wishlistImage.bounds !!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201787/discussion-between-chris-and-arash-etemad).

Answer (score 0):

try this out

1. Problem: 1

`v.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Bold", size: 18)`//delete the space between Avenir & Next

2. Problem: 2 & 3

ad this extension to your project

```
extension UIImageView {

    func addShadow(offset: CGSize, color: UIColor, radius: CGFloat, opacity: Float)
    {
        layer.masksToBounds = false
        layer.shadowOffset = offset
        layer.shadowColor = color.cgColor
        layer.shadowRadius = radius
        layer.shadowOpacity = opacity
    }
}
```

and call this like

```
let wishlistImage: UIImageView = {
        let v = UIImageView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.image = UIImage(named: "logoGroß")
        v.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0
        v.addShadow(offset: CGSize(width: 3, height: 3), color: UIColor.black, radius: 2.0, opacity: 1.0)
        return v
    }()
```

Comment: everything worked perfectly except the corner radius. Any idea how I can fix that as well?

Comment: For rounding corners you should set `layer.masksToBound = true`, and for making shadow you should set it `false`! This is not the solution for adding shadow to rounded image.

Comment: do you know the solution?

Comment: and another thing, I tried changing the font to `medium` instead of `bold` but somehow `AvenirNext-Medium` doesn't work..